# Appropriate number of significant figures to use in plot

Tags: convergence-divergence, graphing-functions, data-analysis, significant-figures

I am trying to illustrate the convergence of a sequence of iterates by means of the following plot:

[convergence plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsKX3.png)

In my discussion I would like to state the fact that 1) the function is monotonically decreasing and 2) the sequence of iterates converge at iteration 13 (as there is no further decrease in the function after this point as shown in sub-figure inside the plot). My concern, however, is that the y-axis label in this plot has too many significant figures. I would be very grateful for some advice on the following points:

a) whether the number of significant figures in the y-axis label should be reduced

b) whether doing a) compromises the aims of my disucssion

Many thanks.

Comment: Why do you say the $y-$axis has too many significant figures?  It seems that without them all, the plot would be meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last three digits of the $y$ values are the only ones that carry any information that varies in the plot. I assume you have reason to believe they are correct. You certainly can't reduce the number of significant digits in the display. But you can consider changing the format.

I think you should display only those three digits on the $y$ axis, perhaps with format `...abc` , with an indication in the text or caption that they are the digits that follow $47.26566$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ethan Bolker. This is precisely the effect I was aiming for! As you've correctly pointed out above, the first 7 digits of the data are pretty much obsolete and can be replaced by '...'. I'm now trying to find a way of actually implementing what you've advised which is proving quite tricky as I am using matlab to generate my plots. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you subtract $47.26566$ from the $y$ values and then multiply by $10^8$ to get an ordinary three digit number to display. The caption can explain what those three digit numbers mean.

Comment: Ethan Bolker Following your suggestion above, I managed to get matlab to replace 47.285662 with '...' and stated in my caption: ''... abbreviates 47.285662''. This has massively improved my presentation. Thanks again for the suggestion!